# How to connect a internal DVD writer of laptop to laptop via USB Adapater

Tags: windows-8

My laptop's internal port of for the DVD-writer isn't working, so I want to connect my laptops inbuilt DVD through usb.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to connect a DVD drive to a laptop via USB, you can purchase an external case, which will plug into a USB port on the laptop. to hold the drive; search online for "external case dvd drive".